# How to access a variable outside a subfunction in javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the following function that uses a `GLTF loader` to load a model into the scene (imported from another class):

```js
    CreateMesh(path){
        this.gltfLoader.load(
            path,
            (gltf) =>
            {
                this.experience.scene.add(gltf.scene)
            }
        )
    }
```

And I call that function from another class like this,  wanting to push to the players array (meant to keep the players meshes) the gltf.scene mesh returned from the `CreateMesh` function.

```js
this.players.push(this.experience.loaderGltf.CreateMesh('./../static/player.glb'))
```

My problem is that I cannot access that variable outside the `gltfLoader.load()` function as you see in the following example:

```js
CreateMesh(path){
     let mesh = null
        this.gltfLoader.load(
            path,
            (gltf) =>
            {
                this.experience.scene.add(gltf.scene)
                mesh=gltf.scene
                console.log(mesh) // prints gltf.scene
            }
        )
      console.log(mesh) //prints "null"
    }
```

Comment: It looks like an async function.  mesh is undefined at the point of the log because the function that initializes it hasn't run yet.

Comment: It's a matter of synchronous and asynchronous code execution. Try using `setTimeout` around your second console.log and see your problem. Why do you need to access `mesh` right after load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `this.gltfLoader.load` is async and doesn't already have a promise-returning variant, handle this by "promisifying" that callback-style function.

```
// return a promise that resolves the result of gltfLoader.load, or "gltf"
async function loadMesh(path) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.gltfLoader.load(path, resolve);
  });
}

// place this where loadMesh is imported and players is in scope...
async createMesh() {
  let gltf = await loadMesh('some/path');
  let mesh=gltf.scene;
  this.experience.scene.add(mesh);
  this.players.push(mesh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading finishes after you log outside the loader so try something like this:

```
CreateMesh(path, callback){
     let mesh = null
        this.gltfLoader.load(
            path,
            (gltf) =>
            {
                this.experience.scene.add(gltf.scene)
                mesh=gltf.scene
                callback(mesh)
            }
        )
    }

CreateMesh('./../static/player.glb', console.log) // Hooraaaa
```

Add to array:

```
this.experience.loaderGltf.CreateMesh('./../static/player.glb', (mesh) => this.players.push(mesh))
```